# CSS: Why doesn't my "Flex item" get a 100% height inside an absolute positioned div?

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have the following markup and css:

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="textContainer">
  <div class="textWrapper">
  <div class="itemOne">
  Item one
  </div>
  <div class="itemTwo">
   Item two
  </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>

.container {
 position: relative;
 height: 500px; 
}

.textContainer {
    position: absolute;
    top: ${theme.spaces.large};
    bottom: ${theme.spaces.large};
    left: ${theme.spaces.large};
    width: 350px;
    z-index: 2;
}

.textWrapper {
   height: 100%;
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Why is the '100%' on the text-wrapper not applied?

Comment: Not sure I have enough context to help, but I would recommend to use an 'element inspector' built in your browser to see what is in the way. Might be a padding or something.

For example, for Google Chrome press F11.

Comment: Is it supposed to be 100% of the text container or the container ? Because your text container just fit with what you put inside which is the text wrapper. If you want your wrapper to have the same height of the container, you need to set the height of the text container before.

Comment: @Cédric `textWrapper` should be 100% height off `container`

Comment: @Cédric  Also when I add ` height: 100%;` to `textContainer` it doesn't work?

Comment: You can check @M.R MRF' answer or mine

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is because `.textContainer` needs to be given a static height value.
`height` only works for elements that have a parent with a static height (in pixels or other units).

Answer (score 0):

Set the `height` of the text container so the text wrappers will take 100% height of it.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  height: 500px;
  width:700px;
}

.textContainer {
  position: absolute;
  width: 350px;
  z-index: 2;
}

.textContainer.left{
  background-color:red;
}
.textContainer.right{
  background-color:gray;
  right:0;
  height:100%;
}


.textWrapper {
   height: 100%;
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="textContainer left">
    <div class="textWrapper">
      <div class="itemOne">
        Item one
      </div>
      <div class="itemTwo">
        Item two
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    
  <div class="textContainer right">
    <div class="textWrapper">
      <div class="itemThree">
        Item three
      </div>
      <div class="itemFour">
        Item four
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/height) the `height` property have not inheritance.
so you should set `height` for `.textWrapper` parent too

```css
.container {
 position: relative;
 height: 500px;
 border: 1px solid;
}

.textContainer {
    position: absolute;
    width: 350px;
    z-index: 2;
    height: 100%;
}

.textWrapper {
   height: 100%;
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   justify-content: space-between;
   background: gold;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="textContainer">
  <div class="textWrapper">
  <div class="itemOne">
  Item one
  </div>
  <div class="itemTwo">
   Item two
  </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```